# Fuzzy Logic implementation through salesforce apex

Tags: apex

I have a development task to implement fuzzy logic matching on Opportunities. We have huge amount of opportunities(running into millions), even after applying certain filters they still run into thousands. I am looking for any example on how to implement fuzzy logic through apex code and any governor limits which I should worry about. Can anyone throw some light here?

Comment: The ideal is to find a way to map the fuzzed version all the fields you are interested in into a single field (or perhaps multiple fields) that you can ask Salesforce to add a custom index to. Then when searching, that index can be used avoiding tables scans. If you have to bring the table rows into Apex to do the work I think you will always be limited by the 50,000 row limit and the 10 seconds of CPU time.